# Set Access Module as a Public Variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set an Access Module as a variable so that I can call certain functions using the variable name and not the actual module name. this will save me a lot of time changing the name of the called module in my forms.

I tried adding a Public variable 'Mod_ActiveModule' as seen below:

```
Public Str_FormLevel_01 As String
Public Str_FormLevel_02 As String
Public Str_FormLevel_03 As String
Public frm_FormLevel_01 As Form
Public frm_FormLevel_02 As Form
Public frm_FormLevel_03 As Form
Public Mod_ActiveModule As Module
```

Shown below is the Sub that I thought would set 'Mod_ActiveModule' to the Module named "Mod_Batches_DP_Pack" - BUT IT ISN'T WORKING!!!!

```
Private Sub cmd_Options_Click()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Str_FormLevel_01 = "frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack"
    Str_FormLevel_02 = "frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack_Edit"
    Str_FormLevel_03 = "frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack_Edit_Detail"

    Set frm_FormLevel_01 = Form_frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack
    Set frm_FormLevel_02 = Form_frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack_Edit
    Set frm_FormLevel_03 = Form_frm_Batches_04_DP_Pack_Edit_Detail

    Set Mod_ActiveModule = Mod_Batches_DP_Pack

    Call ActiveModule.SetUpContextMenu_Level_01
        CommandBars("MenuOptions").ShowPopup

ExitHandler:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "Error On: " & Form.Name & " - cmd_Options_Click"
        Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just pass the form(s) variables to the module routine?

Comment: What is `ActiveModule`?  Did you mean `Mod_ActiveModule`?  And what does it do instead of work?  Do you get an error? Where is the error?

Comment: @braX depending on the form being called the items that are running are very different and not really related to form control items, so passing the form variable wouldnt help me too much.

Comment: @TimWilliams its throwing a **Compile error: Type mismatch**, and yes i did mean `Mod_ActiveModule` but I'm having trouble setting `Mod_ActiveModule = Mod_Batches_DP_Pack` in the first place... what I'm trying to figure out is if I can even declare a VBA Module and then call it. My goal is instead of calling a Query within a specific module like this: `Mod_Batches_DP_Pack.SetUpContextMenu_Level_01`  I want to declare Mod_Batches_DP_Pack = Mod_ActiveModule and then call queries like this: `Mod_ActiveModule .SetUpContextMenu_Level_01`

Comment: A module is not an object - if you want to "namespace" your methods then you can create a class for each set of methods and call them from there.  Assuming Access VBA (not so familiar with that) is more or less like Excel VBA.  I'm not really following why you need this though - you could just as well give your method names fixed prefixes to group them together.

Comment: @TimWilliams The reason I wanted to declare the module as a variable is so that I can copy the module over for each set of forms (there are about 3 forms that interact with the module). If for example, I wanted to add another layer I could simply copy the 3 forms over and then copy the module and only have to change a single reference (the module reference) instead of having to go through all three forms and make sure they are all referencing the correct module.

Comment: why not just declare a set of public functions.  They can be accessed anywhere in access by name.  If you need more encapsulation create a class with the functions and instantiate the class in the code behind for each form so that only those forms can access the code.  Access seems to have been designed long ago, so you have to work with it rather than against it.